# explicitly set "required" in div class using custom FormHelper (cakephp 1.3)

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am using cakephp 1.3, and want to set form inputs as "required" explicitly instead of relying on model validation.  A form input example:

```
<div class="input text required">
  <label for="ClaimClaimantFirstName">First Name</label>
  <input name="data[ClaimClaimant][first_name]" type="text" id="ClaimClaimantFirstName" /> 
</div>
```

I also want to maintain the FormHelper naming instead of using custom form helper names.  Example:

```
$this->Form->input(...)
```

The solution I came up with is

1. implement MyFormHelper, extending from FormHelper and overriding the input method.  Specifically, around line 804 of the FormHelper, replacing

   ```
   if (
     isset($this->fieldset[$modelKey]) 
     && in_array($fieldKey, $this->fieldset[$modelKey]['validates'])
   ) {
     $divOptions = $this->addClass($divOptions, 'required');
   }
   ```

   with

   ```
   if (isset($options['required'])) {
     if ($options['required'] === true) {
       $divOptions = $this->addClass($divOptions, 'required');
     } elseif ($options['required'] === false) {
       // do not add class 'required'
     }
   } elseif (
     isset($this->fieldset[$modelKey]) 
     && in_array($fieldKey, $this->fieldset[$modelKey]['validates'])
   ) {
     $divOptions = $this->addClass($divOptions, 'required');
   }
   ```

   This ensures the presence of `$options['required']` takes precedence before we rely on the model validation.
2. use Joe Beeson's [analogue plugin](https://github.com/joebeeson/analogue), to alias MyForm to Form:

   ```
   public $helpers = array(
     'Analogue.Analogue' => array(
       array(
         'helper' => 'MyForm',
         'rename' => 'Form'
   ) ) )
   ```
3. then, specifying the form input as required looks like:

   ```
   $this->Form->Input(
     'SomeModel.SomeField',
     array('required' => true)
   )
   ```

Is there some other better approach than this, or potential issues with this solution?

Comment: so you want to just have the class required in your div?

Comment: for a better solution try `$this->Form->input('foo', array('div'=>array('class'=>'required')));` but really why go to this trouble when it's in cake out of the box? What are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @Ross using 'div' => array('class' => 'required') does not keep the other classes such as 'text' and 'input'

Comment: @ColbyGuyer I want to have an explicit way to specify whether a form input is required or not (expressed as class required in div).  The explicit way overrides the model validation way of determining if an input is required.

Comment: it sounds like you just want a way for the field to stand out as required. Why not apply your own css. do the 'class'=>'requiredclass' or even an 'after'=>'*' to denote required.

Answer (score 0):

The original question specifies 1.3, but here is an update for those looking for a way in 2.0

For Cake 2.0 or greater you can specify the `'required'=>true` keypair value in your input options array to enable html5 browser validation on the element.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#creating-form-elements